# Printing complex strings in javascript without + symbol

Tags: javascript, syntax, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Is there a more C like way to print complex strings in javascript, preferably one which doesn't require large numbers of the `+` symbol and accompanying `""`?

**I want this:**

```
console.log ( "Name: %s Age: %s Sex %s Wieght %s Height %s", name, age, sex, weight, height );
```

**Instead of this:**

```
console.log ( "Name: " + name + " Age: " + age + " Sex: " + sex + " Weight: " + weight " Height: " + height );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: @Lance my bad. I searched for everything except "javascript ... printf". I'll vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about standard [`window.console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console)? It has exactly the same functionality (tested on Firefox):

```
console.log( "Name: %s Age: %s Sex %s Wieght %s Height %s", name, age, sex, weight, height);
```

Alternatively:

```
console.log( "Name: ", name, " Age: ", sex, " Sex ", sex, " Wieght ", weight", " Height ", height);
```

Comment: well now I feel just plain silly

Answer (score 2):

This library seems to do what you want if you don't mind going third-party.

[JavaScript sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)

*From article*

```
vsprintf('The first 4 letters of the english alphabet are: %s, %s, %s and %s', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

Answer (score 0):

using console.log you can always do this instead of concatenation:

```
console.log ( "Name: ", name, " Age: ", age, " Sex: ", sex, " Weight: ", weight, " Height: " , height );
```

Comment: It's still not as aesthetically pleasing